# overloaded [] operator for both accessing and setting a value (C++)

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, setter, getter

My first time overloading the [] operator for something practical and I ran into something I never thought of before.
I'm trying to make a custom array-like class that holds pointers (and offers some unique features).
Returning one of the pointers from my class by using the [] operator is obvious, but I was also envisioning the ability to change the target address of the pointer from the outside.
Maybe I'm over-thinking this but wouldn't an assignment onto the return value (like fish[0]=lpHatAddress;) cause an error because the value being returned is just an address?

The only solution I've been able to think of is storing pointers to pointers, and that would take twice as much memory.
Am I overlooking something obvious?
Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Show the code of your `[]` overload. I trust that it returns a reference to an element.

Comment: This is nearly the entire reason references were invented.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Sorry. To say I'm rusty would be an understatement. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the result of the operator be a reference. So if your data type is `int`, the operator returns an `int&`.

Comment: Now, that sounds familiar. I'd completely forgotten that return by reference existed. Ironic how going to college for this stuff made me forget half of what I already knew. XD

Comment: @user980058 remember, though, that the only reason you can return by reference and not cause undefined behaviour is because you are storing the objects that you are returning a reference to outside the scope of the function so that the reference refers to a valid area of memory even after the function returns. Make sure you don't ever return a reference to a local variable (I'm sure you knew that already, but I just wanted to be safe).

Answer (score 1):

I think this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12 should help.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick is to use a [proxy (or surrogate) design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy). The idea is to return a temporary object enclosing your target pointer that supports both a conversion to `const T*` pointer and an assignment of `T&` that forwards the assignment to the target pointer. Scott Meyer has a discussion of this pattern in his `More Effective C++` book.